# load() a html with dojo content

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, dojo

i have a simple dojo chart that work's well in a separate file.

now the problem,

if i import the file with `$('#result').load('dojo.html');` nothing happens, the page not loads the graph. If i do a require in a php file, it works...the chart is loaded.

so, the question is: how is the reason that cause the problem when i make a import with the method load();

It is supposed to work? (draw the chart)

thanks

Comment: Do you have a #result in the first place?

Comment: You are using Dojo with jQuery?

Comment: yes it is dojo with jquery. #result in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dojo script must be in the file where the load is made.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true"> </script>
```